# Selenium keep trying to find geckodriver, even when I think I've set it up with Chromedriver while using Ruby 2.3.3

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I'm trying to to get Selenium to use Chrome (via gem 'chromedriver-helper') so I can use capybara.

However, I keep encountering this error in irb -
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.

I'm aware Selenium defaults to Firefox and geckodriver, however my iMac no longer gets MacOS updates, so brew won't download geckodriver.
So, I'm using chromedriver.

Below is what I have typed in irb.

```
2.3.3 :001 > require 'capybara/dsl'
 => true
2.3.3 :002 > require 'selenium-webdriver'
 => true
2.3.3 :003 > include Capybara::DSL
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
 => Object
2.3.3 :004 > Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
 => :selenium
2.3.3 :005 > driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome
 => #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x3f7ff1cdc18a3184 browser=:chrome>
2.3.3 :006 > visit 'http://capybaraworkout.herokuapp.com'
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.
```

I thought the below snippet told Selenium to use Chrome, instead of Firefox!!

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome
```

I'm expecting -
visit 'http://capybaraworkout.herokuapp.com'
to take me to the URL in chrome (as 'visit' is a capybara method)
I know - driver.get 'http://capybaraworkout.herokuapp.com'will take me to the URL, but then when I use another capybara method like - click_link 'Start Workout!' I get the same error (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.)

What do I need to do, to get Capybara to use Chrome via Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a driver with a specific configuration to tell Capybara to use a different browser - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#configuring-and-adding-drivers.  However, if all you want is Selenium using Chrome with a default setup then Capybara already has a driver registered for you - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#selenium

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

That will require you to have chromedriver installed (which the chromedriver-helper gem will do for, although I would recommend using the `webdrivers` gem instead). If you don't want to use selenium/chromedriver then there are a couple of newer options which talk directly to Chrome, one of which is the `appartion` driver - https://github.com/twalpole/apparition

Comment: Unbelievable!! I honestly spent hours trying to figure it out. I did see the github page, I guess I was too far down the rabbit hole to make sense of it. Thanks again for the help.